# Can I change the locale for a single application?

Tags: macos, internationalization

Is it possible to change the locale on a per-application basis in OS X 10.8? Background: I'd like to play "Larry Reloaded" in English, but my user locale is German. The game detects this, and switches to German voices and texts. I don't want to create a new user just for the game, nor do I want to switch the locale manually when starting the game, and back again after quitting.

Comment: Are you using Steam -German account ?

Comment: Using the DRM free version from their website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an AppleLanguages array to the plist of an application:

```
defaults write -app Calculator AppleLanguages -array de
```

See `defaults read -g AppleLanguages` for the language identifiers.

[Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/) is a GUI for doing the same thing.

Comment: Seems like what I need. I will try it out later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update for you hopefully you will still enjoy the game :)

[image]

Note that the game won’t allow the player to select the [desired language](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/leisure_suit_larry_reloaded#reviews=1) - until a patch is released, you’ll have to fix that by **changing your system settings**.